# Event listener when display changes from none to block

Tags: jquery, events, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tabs and I have images in one of the tabs. I need to get their width but the problem is that they are set to `display:none` till I click on that tab so jquery `width()` is always returning 0. I have tried putting it into `window.load` and also `#tabid.load` but none of them work. So is there a way to get width of images in hidden jquery tab? I need their width only when tab is shown so I think there should be some event listener that triggers when selected tab is fully loaded but I havent found it yet. Also tried `on('shown',function())` as described in bootstrap but it also dont work.

EDIT: here is code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
     <li class="active"><a href="#popis" data-toggle="tab">Popis</a></li>
     <li><a href="#recenzie" data-toggle="tab">Recenzie</a></li>
     <li><a href="#galeria" data-toggle="tab">Galéria</a></li>
     <li><a href="#ostatne-produkty" data-toggle="tab" id="#test">Súvisiace produkty</a></li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$('#test').on('shown',alert($('img.product-thumbnail').width()));
```

with this event fires imediatly even before page loads and it show null. Also tried putting id="test" not into href but into actual  but it doesnt work too. Anyway bootstrap documentation says that it should be on  and not in div

Comment: *"Also tried on('shown',function()) as described in bootstrap but it also dont work."* Show the actual code you tried. Code is worth 1,024 words.

Comment: Code uploaded in edit.

Comment: can you see any problem with my event? I dont know why is it firing imediatly at page load and not only on show of tab

Comment: It's running immediately because that's what you told it to do. You're calling the `alert` function and passing *its return value* into `on`. Exactly like `foo(bar())` calls `bar` and passes its return value to `foo`. What you need to pass to `on` is a *function*: `$('#test').on('shown',function() { alert($('img.product-thumbnail').width())});` (that alone may not be the problem, but it was certainly **a** problem).

Comment: and where should I put id test? Into href(tab) or div with content of tab? I have tried both of it but none of them fired event so I've got no alert

Comment: As I found out I was wrong in my previous answer. The images are loaded but not rendered that's why jquery cannot provide sizing information. See my new answer & example. http://jsbin.com/isolif/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `on.('show'` the images are loaded but **not yet rendered**, therefore `$.width` and `$.height` don't provide sizing information.

But you can read directly the `width` and `height` property of the `img` DOM element after `$(window).load`.

See the [example](http://jsbin.com/isolif/6/edit)

If you need the images to be rendered and only then you wish to take their **rendered** sizes, then you should use `on('shown'...`. Which is only triggered after the tab (containing the images) was shown.

I've tried [it out and](http://jsbin.com/isolif/7/edit) it worked as expected

Comment: Good approach, but only if the images are displayed at their native size ^^

Comment: well and here comes the problem ... My images could be resized because I am using this on responsive design so I never know what will the width of image be ... btw tried exactly your solution and I am not getting any console logs. Still looks like there is problem with this event because it never fires